# ¿Was "grosso modo" popularised from Latin or Italian?

Tags: etymology, idiom, italian

*[Grosso modo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grosso_modo#Latin)* is a phrase of Latin origin, meaning "approximately". The phrase has been adopted in many languages (like English, French, Dutch, etc), as the referred link testifies. The interesting thing is this: **the phrase is also native Italian**.

According to [this](https://www.thelocal.fr/20190118/french-expression-of-the-day-grosso-modo) unscientific blog entry, it has been used at least since the XIVth century. That is quite late Latin and a time where romances languages (like Italian) were already developing fast.

The question is then, are we sure the **popularisation** of such phrase emanate from the Latin (as it seems to be believed) rather than from the Italian? I would imagine the answer hinges on an analysis of the corpus of where such phrase is adopted, for instance, scientific (Latin) versus literary (Italian) work. I couldn't know how to perform such analysis, let alone if it is the right approach. Any ideas?

Comment: The phrase is used adverbially, which works because it is in the ablative. I guess that would not work in Italian without some further adornment, like *in grosso modo*, right?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: Yes, if it were not a crystallised borrowing, some adornment would be needed.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel That sounds like an answer actually.

Answer (score 2):

from Du Cange, et al., Glossarium mediae et infimae Latinitatis, Niort: L. Favre, 1883–1887 (10 vol.). searchable full-text online edition, by the École nationale des chartes:

http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/GROSSUS1#GROSSUS1-5

[image]

Zingarelli 2021 gives **1657** as the earliest recorded attestation in Italian (no more information provided), cf. for [French](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/grosso-modo) it is **1566**, whereas in Latin it is **1319** (as you can see above).

A simple search in [Early English Books Online](https://www.english-corpora.org/eebo/) gives at least seven occurrences before the first Italian attestation (the earliest one in English is **1607**):

[image]

What might shed more light on this is a corpus study of Italian uses but I am not aware of historical Italian corpora.

Another sign could be this: if indeed it became more frequent in the European languages due to its use in Italian, we would see comments in the European languages something like, as they say/write in Italian etc. or even glosses next to it.